# HTML Form in Laravel Form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm searching for a couple of time for some formulars for Laravel and of course I found a lot. But there are still some things I need to change them.

This is the orginal form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and thats how I changed them:

```
            {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Auth\\AuthController@postLogin')) !!}
                Email
                <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"><br><br>
                Password
                {!! Form::password('password', array('id' => 'password')) !!}<br>
                {!! Form::checkbox('remember') !!} Remember Me
                {!! Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Things I need to change:

the whole 'email input', with the {{ old('email) }} insite the laravel form.

And I don't like to write: Email/Password/Remember me/ outsite of the Form.

Can someone give me this as a laravel form?

Comment: Maybe ` Form::label('emailLabel', 'Email');`

Comment: well I did that:  '' {!! Form::text('email_address', "{{ old('email') }}") !!} '' --- beside the {{ old('email') }} everything works.. the thing is, I really need that. So does anybody know how I can use this?

Comment: What do You mean by "Email/Password/Remember me as a laravel form"?

Comment: {!! Form::email('email_address', old('email_address'), ['class' => 'field']) !!}

Comment: I mean that it's now written in HTML, but I want it like in the end of my code :) so I want to use the Form:: package :)  -- does anybody know how I can say insite the form, that I want a text before the textbox ?  like : Email : ( Email Textbox )

Comment: Unless You are using old (4.2 or below) Laravel, Form facade is no longer a part of Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{!! Form::email('email', old('email', null), ['id' => 'input-id']) !!}
```

You just need to understand which parameters `Form::input()` can take
Usually

1. name
2. value
3. array for options (like id, class, autocomplete and etc)

Input with placeholder

```
{!! Form::email('email', old('email', null), ['placeholder' => old('email','default@email.com')]) !!}
```

Here I have `old('email', null)` where is null is default value, you can change it to anything you want, to be shown by defaul if `email` is empty

```
Labels
Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address', ['class'=>'my-class']);
```

Comment: thanks, I'm using this :) can you say me how can say the Form that I want something like a text before the form? like: Email: " email form " ?

Comment: thanks! works perfect for me :) I thought maybe there is another way to say  that I want a text before the form, without doing a label hehe. Well, works, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

`{!! Form::email('email', old('email')) !!}`

or

`{!! Form::text('email', old('email')) !!}`

**Labels**

If You want to change these texts into labels You can, for example:

`{!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail') !!}` instead of `E-mail`

Comment: this works perfect :) well, now I just want to get a : Email : -- before the Form.. now its just a textbox without anything written before. I know there was a way in the form, to get a text written next to the textbox. I just don't remember how :o

Comment: @ItzMe488 this may work at a visual level, but it will create an input with type `text` not `email`, so you won't have the validation offered by an `email` input.

Comment: I changed it back and forth. I depends what You wanna achieve.

Comment: @Bogdan It have nothing to do with Laravel validation. It's only different input type, so different browser behavior only.

Comment: @D.Cichowski I did not write the word Laravel anywhere in my comment. I was saying that the `email` input type comes with value validation according to [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.value.single) ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/3et3hdue/1/)). And since the OP was explicitly using `type="email"` then it stands to reason that was the intended usage.